# Oracle to SQL Server: Date Conversion & Format

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2012

I'm in the process of migrating our Data Warehouse from Oracle to SQL Server 2012.

One piece of code I use a hundred times a day in Oracle is changing the date format for a query by using something like:

```
To_Char(entry_date,'WMMYY') = 30612
```

The above allows me to grab the date (default format = `DD-MON-YY` eg `01-JAN-12`) and change the format for the week specified (the third week of June in the above example) by simply listing the week desired.

In my mind the above is very simple and easy to use. I can change it to whatever format I want (MMYY, MMYYYY) etc. without any issues. So far I cannot figure out an easy way to do this in SQL Server 2012 and it's really starting to bother me. It's `datetime2` in SQL Server.

I'm finding stuff for `CAST(), CONVERT(), DATEPART()` but from what I've seen there is all kinds of wacky coding and number codes (like 101, 102, I don't understand why this is) required which just seems extraneous and over complicated to me.

Have I just not found what I'm looking for yet or is this just the way it is with SQL Server? I just want to be able to do something simple like grab all the data that was entered in during the month of june or the second week of october without having to add 200 extra characters of code.

Comment: Moving from Oracle to SQL Server is a huge step back when it comes to date handling (and a lot of other things). As far as I can tell, you will need to write your own function for this

Answer (score 0):

It's a switch.  You are using SQL Server 2012, so look into `FORMAT()` function. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28SQL.110%29.aspx  I'm not, so unfortunately I can't test anything out for you - but there are some date formatting improvements. 
For those of us who aren't - , there are things you can do that will be great - once you get used to them.  This isn't specific to SQL Server - but Week of Month varies from organization to organization - so you'd have to define that to get a good example for  3rd week of month, etc.  Also, when using `DATEPART` with week or day arguments, what gets returned is determined by the setting for the first day of the week (1 -7 - `@@DATEFIRST`).  The numeric styles for `CONVERT` (again check out `FORMAT()` if you're on 2012) are definitely not as intuitive - but you'll probably be using the same styles over and over, and you'll have them memorized quickly.  If you are set on 'WMMYY' or just use something over and over that doesn't have a satisfactory built in solution- create a `UDF`.

data that was entered in during the month of june

```
   DATEPART(mm,@date) = 6
```

current month

```
  month(getDate())
```

Or this week

```
  DATEPART(ww,GetDate())
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I didn't realize SQL Server was such a step back from Oracle when it comes to date handling. It just seems like such common sense and I'm sure there are thousands of people using SQL server to do exactly what I need. It looks like it will just be a bit of an adjustment. I'll look into FORMAT(). Thanks again.